# Simple Expression - Lambert W function

Tags: probability, closed-form, lambert-w

I have all the below variables except for $a$, is there a closed form expression for $a$ with respect of the rest of the variables?

> $$\lambda=\frac{1+(\ln (a)-\mu) / \sigma^{2}}{a}$$

What I have so far:

$\lambda a  = 1 + (\ln(a) - \mu) / \sigma^2$

$\sigma^2[\lambda a-1]= \ln(a) - \mu$

$\sigma^2\lambda a-\sigma^2= \ln(a) - \mu$

$\sigma^2\lambda a- \ln(a)=  \sigma^2 - \mu $

Thanks

Comment: I tried optimization functions that figures out "a", having the rest of the variables in place, but maybe there is closed form expression which can be used that saves some computational power.

Comment: I cannot get passed $\lambda a - \ln (a) = \sigma^2 + \mu$

Comment: sure thanks i'll add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\lambda=\frac{1+\frac{\ln a-\mu}{\sigma^2}}{a}&\implies\lambda=\frac{\sigma^2+\ln a-\mu}{\sigma^2a}\\&\implies\lambda\sigma^2a=(\sigma^2-\mu)+\ln a\\&\implies\frac1{e^{\sigma^2-\mu}}=ae^{-\lambda\sigma^2a}\\&\implies-\frac{\lambda\sigma^2}{e^{\sigma^2-\mu}}=-\lambda\sigma^2ae^{-\lambda\sigma^2a}\\&\implies W\left(-\frac{\lambda\sigma^2}{e^{\sigma^2-\mu}}\right)=-\lambda\sigma^2a\\&\implies a=-\frac1{\lambda\sigma^2}W\left(-\frac{\lambda\sigma^2}{e^{\sigma^2-\mu}}\right)\end{align}

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll use this in python instead of optimization

Comment: @AAC: just a reminder: if the argument 
$x=-\frac{\lambda\sigma^2}{e^{\sigma^2-\mu}}$,
$x\in(-\tfrac1{\mathrm e},0)$
then there would be two real solutions.

Comment: @g.kov yes I noticed this issue of having solutions with complex numbers... I'm going to use a different approach to tackle this... thanks though

Answer (score 1):

As $a$ appears outside and inside a logarithm, there is no closed-form expression using the standard functions. This can probably be solved with $W$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: thanks, so there is no closed expression.... that answers it